# Is it possible to load a razor component from a string and use it inside Blazor page?

Tags: svg, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to dynamically load SVG from string and use it inside Blazor page. Because I want to use parameters of this svg, so I think svg should be inside a razor component, for example:

```
<svg>
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="@Radius" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="@BackColor" />
</svg>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string BackColor { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to load such a component above from a string (from database or from uploaded file, it doesn't matter) and render it in my page and use its parameters. Is it possible to do it ?

I tried to use DynamicComponent, but DynamicComponent requires to provide a known type of component, but inside a project the type is not known, I have only a content loaded from external source.

Comment: I think you'll have to do this manually.  Something like `svgstring.Replace("@BackColor", "#ff0000");  Oh, Henk already siad that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show an SVG string by casting it to a MarkupString.

```
  @((MarkupString)svgText)
```

But that won't process the `@BackColor`. You could do your own replacements, either with strings, RegEx or XElement.

Comment: Using regex won't be very nice i think :), I thought about this solution before, but I was hoping to do it differently. I also tried using a RenderFragment class, but that also wouldn't let me process the parameters.

Comment: Blazor will only process the `@Parameter`s at compile time, yiour data only becomes available at runtime. I see no other way.

Comment: why are you dont want to use (MarkupString)string.Format("<circle fill=""{0}"">", BackColor) ?

Comment: I tried (Markup String)string.Format and XElement. They works well. But I have performance concerns with large SVG files. When SVG is statically embedded (at compile time), only the elements values change when parameters are changed. In my case, when the SVG is loaded at runtime, the whole SVG is replaced when the parameters values are changed. Could this make a difference with large SVG files?

Comment: ![screenshot](https://ibb.co/WvVPDrS)

Comment: Yes, the embedded version will probably be faster, but it will be passed  through BuildRenderTree() each time. Test it with a worst-case file.

Comment: If the loaded version is too slow you could try a custom rendering from an XElement. Still slower than the pre-compiled embedded version. I have no idea how it would perform.

Comment: Anyway, the proposed @((MarkupString)svgText is the solution to my problem, thank you.